# How to use SQL minus query equivalent between two dataframes properly

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes each having 1000 rows. The dataframes are same, however, row by row is not same. The following examples can be assumed as truncated version of the dataframes.

```
df1:

col1 col2 col3

1      2    3
2      3    4
5      6    6
8      9    9

df2:

col1 col2 col3

5      6    6
8      9    9
1      2    3
2      3    4
```

The dataframes don't have indices and I expect null returned when I implement sql minus query on these. I used the following query, but did not obtain the result as expected. Is there any way to achieve my desired result ?

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(),how='right', indicator=True)
print(df3)
```

For instance, if I consider *df1* as **table1** and df2 as **table2**, and if I ran the following query in SQL server, I would get null returned (empty table).

```
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: you could try: ``df1.loc[df1.isin(df2).any(1)]`` or ``df1.merge(df2, indicator=True).query("_merge!='both'").drop(columns="_merge")``, or ``df1.merge(df2, indicator=True).iloc[lambda df: df.iloc[:, -1].ne("both").array, :-1]``. If i understand correctly, you are looking for something like an anti join, where none of df2 are in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the indicator like this:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='ind').query('ind=="left_only"')
```

Where df1 is:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1   2.0   3.0   4.0
2   5.0   6.0   6.0
3   8.0   9.0   9.0
4  10.0  10.0  10.0
```

and df2 is:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     5     6     6
1     8     9     9
2     1     2     3
3     2     3     4
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3        ind
4  10.0  10.0  10.0  left_only
```